# React, Redux, Firebase: Infinite Loop while trying to get value from useSelector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux

SO i am learning firebase along with redux, creating a todo app. I encountered an infinite loop while i try to get the data from redux. Here's my code:

TodoPage.jsx

```html
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { db } from "../firebase-config";
import { doc, setDoc, getDocs, collection } from "firebase/firestore";
import { auth } from "../firebase-config";
import { signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import nextId from "react-id-generator";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import { taskInfo } from "../redux/userReducer";

function ToDoPage() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [user, loading] = useAuthState(auth);
  const htmlId = nextId();
  const [newTask, setNewTask] = useState("");
  const [newDuration, setNewDuration] = useState("");
  const tasks = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  if (loading) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>This page is currently loading</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  const getTaskList = async () => {
    try {
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(
        collection(db, "users", user.uid, "tasks")
      );
      dispatch(
        taskInfo({
          querySnapshot,
        })
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
  getTaskList();
  const taskRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid, "tasks", htmlId);
  const createTask = async () => {
    try {
      await setDoc(
        taskRef,
        { task: newTask, duration: newDuration },
        { merge: false }
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
  const signoutUser = () => {
    signOut(auth)
      .then(() => {
        console.log(auth);
        console.log("sign-out success");
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };

  return (
    <TodoContainer>
      <h1>The user id logged in is : {user ? user.uid : "none"}</h1>
      <InputContainer>
        <input
          onChange={(e) => {
            setNewTask(e.currentTarget.value);
          }}
          placeholder="Enter Task"
        />
        <input
          onChange={(e) => {
            setNewDuration(e.currentTarget.value);
          }}
          placeholder="Enter Duration"
        />
        <Button onClick={createTask}>Create Task</Button>
      </InputContainer>
      <TaskListContainer>
        <h1>To Do List</h1>
        <Todo></Todo>
      </TaskListContainer>
      <button onClick={signoutUser}>Sign Out</button>
    </TodoContainer>
  );
}

export default ToDoPage;

const TodoContainer = styled.div``;

const InputContainer = styled.div``;

const Button = styled.button``;

const TaskListContainer = styled.div``;

const Todo = styled.div``;
```

```html
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../firebase-config";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function Login() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const loginUser = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        if (userCredential) {
          history.push("/");
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };
  const createUser = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        const user = userCredential.user;
        console.log(user);
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  };
  return (
    <LoginContainer>
      <form>
        <h3>Email</h3>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <h3>Password</h3>
        <input
          type="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button onClick={loginUser}>Log In</button>
      </form>
      <button onClick={createUser}>Create Account</button>
    </LoginContainer>
  );
}

export default Login;

const LoginContainer = styled.div`
  > form {
    > button {
      margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
      display: flex;
    }
  }
`;
```

UserReducer.jsx

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    taskInfo: (state, action) => {
      const data = [];
      const taskData = action.payload;
      taskData.querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        data.push(doc.data());
      });
      console.log(data);
      if (action.payload !== "") {
        return {
          task: data,
        };
      } else {
        return {
          task: "",
        };
      }
    },
  },
});

export const { taskInfo } = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

[image: Infinite Loop]

The problem occured only when i used the useSelector hook. Trying to understand what is going on and what is causing the re-render. Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you call `getTaskList()` on every render of the `TodoPage.jsx`. Any line of code that is in the functional component is run on every render.

To solve this, try putting the call to `getTaskList()` in a `useEffect()`

```
useEffect(() => getTaskList(), []);
```

Comment: If i put getTaskList() in useEffect, the value of uid will be null or undefined as it isn't loaded yet due to async await. Therefore the error:
               TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null

Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried with useEffect in the first time but it still didn't work